# Removing an upvote/downvote without reversing the vote

Tags: support, voting

Is there a way to remove an upvote/downvote without reversing the vote?

Comment: The only way is to reverse the vote.  Why do you want remove the vote?

Comment: @Ramhound No. Reverting vote means: change an up to a down, or a down to up. Removing the vote means: making a voted post to un-voted. Both are possible until 5 mins after your last voting change or the last edit.

Comment: @peterh - By changing your vote, you are reversing the vote you did issue and issuing the other vote.  I don't really see the distinction to be honest.  I the reason I don't see a distinction is because, if its been more then 5 minutes, you can't **change** your vote.  So either case, the original vote, is reversed.

Answer (score 5):

- Click again on an upvote to remove an upvote without downvoting
- Click again on a downvote to remove a downvote without upvoting

After 5 minutes your vote will be locked though and can't then be changed unless the post is edited.

Comment: ...what also you also do over 2k, but editing a question only to change the vote is obviously not a very positive behavior.

Comment: If the OP edits the question and either improves it or makes it worse then changing your vote is perfectly fine isn't it? Also if the OP adds comments that claify the question and you edit them into the question what's wrong with also changing your vote then? In short, there are plenty of positive scenarios.